How to delete members of a list by rule
I have a list:
lis = {"a",1,""}

and would like to delete from the list all elements that consist of "" to give:
res = {"a",1}

Thanks for help with this simple question.

Please use search prior to posting a new question. There are many questions about deleting elements from a list.

{"a", 1, ""} /. "" -> Nothing


{"a", 1}

